# Meta Like button disappear in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I put a like button on my website, based on this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button,
I have a strange problem because I can see the facebook button after logging in as admin in wp. When I log out, the button disappears (iframe with like button don't load content).

Comment: did you see the large info section at the beginning of that page? might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks, maybe that's the reason. As usual, the great communist government of the EU has implemented a great law.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the reason:

> We will no longer support the 'Like' and 'Comment' Social Plugins for
> European Region users, unless they are both 1) Logged into their
> Facebook account, and 2) have provided consent to the “App and Website
> Cookies” control. If both of these requirements are met, the user will
> be able to see and interact with plugins such as the 'Like' or
> 'Comment' button. If either of the requirements above are not met, the
> user will not be able to see the plugins.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button